# IPC Port Access Denied

Tags: windows, powershell, mstest, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute `mstest` remotely via `Invoke-Command` in PowerShell.  The PowerShell command within the scriptblock is a basic `mstest` call with a single test container and a specified results file.  It works correctly if run from within RDP on the remote server.

However, if I run it remotely via `Invoke-Command`, `mstest` returns an exception

> Failed to queue test run 'Administrator@AEPRFDLY00ALL00 2016-01-06 10:22:40': Unable to start the agent process.

Looking at event viewer on the remote machine, I see a series of exceptions, starting with:

```
(QTAgent32_40.exe, PID 2432, Thread 1) AgentProcess: Failed to get agent process proxy: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to connect to an IPC Port: Access is denied.
Server stack trace: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcPort.Connect(String portName,             Boolean secure, TokenImpersonationLevel impersonationLevel, Int32 timeout)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.ConnectionCache.GetConnection(String portName, Boolean secure, TokenImpersonationLevel level, Int32 timeout)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.IAgentProcessManagerAccessManager.GetAgentProcessProxy(String executionKey)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.AgentProcess.GetAgentProcessProxy()
```

I am executing the command using `Invoke-Command` using the same credentials used for RDP (in which session the command is successful).  Also, in the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock, if I call `whoami /priv`, I see a response with 23 privilege names.  Based on my previous research, this means I'm running in an elevated session.  `Invoke-Command` is using Authentication = Negotiate.

I don't think that this is a firewall issue because I can run other commands from within the scriptblock successfully, just not `mstest`, so the PowerShell session is starting on the remote machine.

Note that this is detailed in [this forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4c09a282-2d3c-47db-b1bb-2c98a531226a/ps-remoting-failed-to-connect-to-an-ipc-port-access-is-denied?forum=winserverpowershell) but without resolution.

Comment: any adventurous guessers?

Comment: Sorry, no guesses, but I'm seeing this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding that the `/noisolation` option to MSTEST.EXE fixes this - probably because it obviates the spawning of the QTAgent32_40.exe process and so also the need for the IPC channel.